# QRegExp to extract string between a tag in html

Tags: regex, qt, parsing, qregexp

The situation is tricky as I do not have access to webkits on qt module, I am forced to parse an HTML file using QRegExp:

The file contains strings which I need to extract which are well placed between li tags.

If I write a QRegExp

```
QRegExp ("[^</li>]([a-zA-Z0-9_./]+)");
```

I could Extract all the strings between li tag. But all I need are:

Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_2

Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_3

Pg_1_qds_Ana_Indicator_1 *and all the names similar to this enclosed between li*

someother names include which are not in the part of the file enclosed but there in the full file:
TEMPLATE_LOGO

Pg_1_Command_By_Text

All the names start with Pg_ except for one which is TEMPLATE_LOGO_

I feel that the other lines have characters like [ , or another tag in between to identify that the string is not needed in that line.

The file is found below, 
So, TL;DR
Need a QRegExp to extract the above mentioned names found in between the li tags.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#symbols">Symbol report</a></li>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#symbolsConsistency">Consistency</a></li>
  <li><a href="#symbolCharacteristics">Symbol characteristics</a></li>
  <li><a href="#basicSymbols">Display of basic symbols</a></li>


    <ul>
      <li>Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_2</li>
    <ul>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionalignment] = (Right)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptiontextcolor] = (Color {0, 0, 0, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.isdescriptiondisplayed] = (true)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontfamily] = (Arial)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontsize] = (11 pt)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontstyle] = (Normal)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontposition] = (LEFT)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptiontext] = (v1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.backgroundcolor] = (Color {238, 238, 238, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.digitnumber] = (8)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.widgetfont] = (FONT1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.shortname] = (Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_2)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.precision] = (2)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.widgetuserfontfamily] = (Arial)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.widgetuserfontsize] = (11 pt)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.widgetuserfontstyle] = (NORMAL)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.dynamicbackgroundcolor] = (Color {238, 238, 238, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.longname] = (Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_2_v1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.heith] = (32)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.weigth] = (50)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.poxX] = (352)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.poxY] = (116)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.valuealignment] = (Left)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.value_0] = (Off)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.value_1] = (On)</li>
    </ul>
      <li>Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_3</li>
    <ul>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionalignment] = (Right)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptiontextcolor] = (Color {0, 0, 0, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.isdescriptiondisplayed] = (true)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontfamily] = (Arial)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontsize] = (11 pt)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontstyle] = (Normal)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.descriptionfontposition] = (LEFT)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptiontext] = (v1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.backgroundcolor] = (Color {238, 238, 238, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.digitnumber] = (8)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.widgetfont] = (FONT1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.shortname] = (Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_3)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.precision] = (2)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.widgetuserfontfamily] = (Arial)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.widgetuserfontsize] = (11 pt)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.widgetuserfontstyle] = (NORMAL)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.dynamicbackgroundcolor] = (Color {238, 238, 238, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.longname] = (Pg_1_qds_Bin_Indicator_3_v1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.heith] = (32)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.weigth] = (50)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.poxX] = (446)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.poxY] = (187)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.valuealignment] = (Left)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.value_0] = (Off)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.logicIndicator.value_1] = (On)</li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
    <p><em>Analog indicator :</em></p>
    <ul>
      <li>Pg_1_qds_Ana_Indicator_1</li>
    <ul>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptionalignment] = (Right)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptiontextcolor] = (Color {0, 0, 0, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.isdescriptiondisplayed] = (true)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptionfontfamily] = (Arial)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptionfontsize] = (11 pt)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptionfontstyle] = (Normal)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptionfontposition] = (LEFT)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.descriptiontext] = (v0)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.backgroundcolor] = (Color {238, 238, 238, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.digitnumber] = (8)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.widgetfont] = (FONT1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.shortname] = (Pg_1_qds_Ana_Indicator_1)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.precision] = (2)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.widgetuserfontfamily] = (Arial)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.widgetuserfontsize] = (11 pt)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.widgetuserfontstyle] = (NORMAL)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.dynamicbackgroundcolor] = (Color {238, 238, 238, 255})</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.longname] = (Pg_1_qds_Ana_Indicator_1_v0)</li>
      <li>[QDSConsistency.report.field.analogIndicator.heith] = (32)</li>
```

Comment: "and all the names similar to this enclosed between li", what do you mean by similar? We'll need some kind of concrete way to know what to match. Is it any alphanumeric string (allows underscores) that starts with "Pg_1"?

Comment: All names start with Pg_1 except for one which is TEMPLATE_LOGO

Comment: Try `<li>[^>]*?(?:Pg_|TEMPLATE_LOGO_)[^>]*?</li>`

Comment: it is Pg_ not Pg_1 still doesnt work

Comment: I'd use `QRegExp("\\b(?:Pg_|TEMPLATE_LOGO)\\w+")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG9aZ8/1)). If you say "does not work", always explain *how* it works, what happens when you use the regex.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yN3bR6/3
still no luck

Comment: No idea what you mean "no luck". Explain what is wrong. and what you expect.Every regex here works, they just match different strings, and no one knows what you need except for you.

Comment: The thing is I would want strings only <li> Pg_1_Ana</li>,
not strings <li>[QDS.report.name] = Pg_1_Ana</li>;
so the expression extracts all Pg_1_Ana the string is between the tag<li></li>, no extraction should be done from the other values

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yG9aZ8/2 ure solution led to the final soultion and if u could post this I would close this post but i need to improve it for TEMPLATE_LOGO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [regex101.com/r/yG9aZ8/2](https://regex101.com/r/yG9aZ8/2) ure solution led to the final soultion
>   and if u could post this I would close this post but i need to improve
>   it for TEMPLATE_LOGO

Then just add a *2nd Alternative: TEMPLATE_LOGO.**:

```
QRegExp exp1("<li>(Pg_.*|TEMPLATE_LOGO_.*)<\\/li>");
```

Credit Goes to Mr. Trey and Mr. Wiktor Stribiżew,their answers led to the solution that is desired.

Comment: I can agree but this answer doesnt suit to QRegExp, if you could edit your post as per QRegExp, I will delete my comment and close this post

Comment: @Sivaramakrishna Shriraam: Not to bother with; feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: You are a nice person, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to Mr. Trey and  Mr. Wiktor Stribiżew,their answers led to the solution that is desired.

```
QRegExp exp1("<li>(Pg_.*|TEMPLATE_LOGO_.*)<\\/li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, see if this works for you: `<li>.*\((Pg_1[^)]*|TEMPLATE_LOGO).*?<\/li>`

Should match any string beginning with "Pg_1", or specifically "TEMPLATE_LOGO", that are found between `li` tags.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not forced to parse html using `QRegExp`. A **regular** expression matcher can only match **regular** syntax languages. HTML isn't a language with regular syntax. So [**it will not ever reliably work.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) Use an HTML parser! I suggest [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser). It's a stand-alone C-based parser with an easy to use API.

Comment: The problem is linking qt and gumbo in an application. My project is fully developed using Qt FrameWork. And the PC I am working is never connected to the internet(Air gapped). I have limited time frame to achieve this functionality

Comment: It's trivial to compile gumbo using qmake. Just add a top-level project for it and it will work. Alas, I can't force you to do anything.

Comment: I understand that the thing you have suggested is very easy. But the problems from my sides are: I would have to obtain a company authorized usb  and I should request access to download content, this content will be reviewed by the IT, then would I be allowed to install gumbo into my air gapped pc which in turn shall take a bit of documentation.

Comment: Your question is missing this critical bit of information, then!